# Can I replace ‘failed in’ by ‘failed to’ in the sentence?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> I had failed in every attempt to find her.

Can I replace ‘failed in’ by ‘failed to’ in this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Not without rewriting / re-shaping the sentence. You could write:

> Every attempt to find her had failed.

or

> I had failed to find her, even after trying everything

but not "I had failed to every attempt..."

In general one can say "I had failed to {verb}" but not "I had failed to {noun}. Examples:

> - I had failed to finish the job
> - I had failed to get the job done.
> - I had failed to win the prize.
> - I had failed to slay the dragon.
> - I had failed to make good on my promise

But not

- I had failed to the right of way. ("yield"  omitted)
- I had failed to upward. ("move" or "climb" omitted)

The same principle apples to any "I had Xed to Y" where X is a verb, so Xed is a past-tense form of the verb, Y needs to be a verb or a phrase acting as a verb.

> - She stooped to conquer.
> - He wanted to become a surgeon.
> - The Assembly proceeded to pass a law.

Comment: Is this sentence right ‘I had failed to attempt to find her’?

Comment: @Y. zeng That is grammatical, but means that you didn't even try. "Attempt" here is a verb. in "every attempt" the word "attempt" is functioning as a noun. The meaning is quite different.

Answer (score 0):

No. "In every attempt" is a prepositional phrase that is functioning as an adverb to modify "failed."  Replacing "in" with "to" removes the meaning of the phrase, and duplicates the "to" unnecessarily.

The base of the sentence is:

> I had failed [...] to find her.
>
> I had failed in every attempt to find her.